# Ruby: Run script from bash script?

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to call a Ruby script from a bash script, but no luck.

```
#!/bin/bash
ruby -v
```

works just fine, so I know that it's not Ruby, but

```
#!/bin/bash
ruby bash_test.rb
```

does not. Here's the fun part:

```
john@starfire:~/Desktop$ bash ubuntu_cmds.sh
(LoadError)h file or directory -- bash_test.rb
john@starfire:~/Desktop$ ls *.rb
bash_test.rb
```

Both files are sitting on my desktop.

```
ruby bash_test.rb
```

works just fine, too.

I'm new to bash scripting, so I'm pretty sure that I'm just making a stupid error.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 with Ruby 1.8.7. Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

EDIT: Deleted the .sh and the .rb and started over, and made sure to `chmod +x` the .sh, and it worked on the first try. I have no idea why. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: Please see my edit; the best way to format blocks of code is to indent them by 4 spaces, or select them and press the `{}` button.

Comment: Ahh, thanks... that is much nicer. I appreciate it.

Comment: For the benefit of those looking for the `{}` button on their keyboard, @meagar's referring to the icon above the question editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a carriage return in the bash script after the file name ?

---

*EDITED*

Double check how the filename is being passed to ruby in the bash script.

Error output should be as below if the file wasn't found

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- bash_test.rb (LoadError)
```

From what you are displaying as an error it appears that there is a carriage return that is being assumed by ruby as part of the filename so you are getting the following error output.

```
 (LoadError)h file or directory -- bash_test.rb
```

Comment: @kivetros: It's not "do you" it's "you do". Run `dos2unix` against your script.

Comment: I ended up just deleting both the script and the .rb and starting over... mysteriously enough, both worked just fine on the first try. dos2unix is really cool, though - thanks for the heads-up on that.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
#!/bin/bash
ruby ~/Desktop/bash_test.rb
```

Comment: `(LoadError)h file or directory -- /home/john/Desktop/bash_test.rb` :P Should've mentioned that I tried that already.

Answer (score 3):

You may have to do `ruby ./bash_test.rb`, as sometimes `.` isn't in your `$PATH`.